# Remove/delete a string of characters from filenames

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a bunch of text files that end with the line `www.thethinkfoundation.org`, for example:

```
file1.www.thethinkfoundation.org.txt
file2.www.thethinkfoundation.org.txt
.
.
.

file100.www.thethinkfoundation.org.txt
```

I wish to remove/delete `www.thethinkfoundation.org`

I tried the following command in a terminal to achieve it:

```
for f in www.thethinkfoundation.org*; do mv "$f" "${f#thethinkfoundation.org}"; done
```

The result was:

```
file1..txt
file2..txt
.
.
.

file100..txt
```

Thank you in advance for a solution that works.

P.S.: I do not wish to use the `rename` command. I am actually looking for one that works across Linux and *BSD distros. My preferred text editor is `nano`.

Answer (score 5):

Sub-string replacement based on *Shell Parameter Expansion* in `bash` and a few other shells as well can be achieved in two ways:

**First**, you can replace **only the first occurrence**(*from left to right*) of a pattern like so:

```
${var/pattern/replacement}
```

**Second**, you can replace **all occurrences** of a pattern like so:

```
${var//pattern/replacement}
```

Where `var` is the variable/parameter containing the string and `pattern` is the pattern that you wish to find and replace in that string and `replacement` is the replacement that you wish to substitute that `pattern` with which can be left empty as well i.e. `${var//pattern/}` if you wish to just delete that pattern from the string.

Therefore, your desired solution would look like this:

```bash
for f in *www.thethinkfoundation.org*; do
    echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f//www.thethinkfoundation.org./}"
done
```

I added `echo` for a dry-run so that you can test it first and then take out `echo` and run it again to do the real work.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial which I find very helpful to my understanding of how your solution works. But what do the `-n` and the two dashes `-- `mean? I ask because they do not appear in your first answer.

Comment: @alien.on.earth The `-n` also `--no-clobber` option means "do not overwrite an existing file" in case a file with the same name already exists ... and the `--` indicates the end of options so that `mv` doesn't choke on filenames which start with a `-`  ... Both are safety measures that are good to set in such case but `mv` should work without them (overwriting existing files and choking on filenames starting with `-` if they occur though :-) ... You don't want that) that's why.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.